# Text gets auto Tweeted while Media (image) does not

Tags: php, twitter

I am using this ridiculously simple script to auto Tweet on behalf of a user.

```
$image = 'test.jpg';

// Insert your keys/tokens
$consumerKey = 'xxx';
$consumerSecret = 'xxx';
$OAuthToken = 'xxx';
$OAuthSecret = 'xxx';

// Full path to twitterOAuth.php (change OAuth to your own path)
require_once('connect/twitter/twitteroauth.php');

$params = array(
    'status' => $_REQUEST['content'],
    'media[]' => '@{$image}'
);

// create new instance
$tweet = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $OAuthToken, $OAuthSecret);

// Send tweet
$tweet->post('statuses/update', $params);
```

Upon executing this code, text gets Tweeted on my twitter account however the image does not. I have been previously advised to only attempt tweeting local files and I was advised this is the proper way to specify the media[].

Why isnt this posting the image while its posting the text to twitter?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `statuses/update_with_media` - not `statuses/update` (which you are currently using).

For more information, [please read the documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update_with_media).

Comment: I have tried this before and I tried again to double check but with this change nothing gets posted to Twitter, not even the text.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using the Abraham Library. It won't work for Tweet with Media. I was in the position last month & this [library](https://github.com/robhaswell/twitteroauth) helped me. Just Download & Copy the `twitteroauth` folder from the extracted folder & paste it in your project folder by renaming it into `twitteroauth1`. Why because, there might a folder `twitteroauth` or files `twitteroauth.php` & 'oAuth.php` already present in the Abraham Library.

Now, you just want to edit the include or require_once as

```
require_once('twitteroauth1/twitteroauth.php');
```

The new twitteroauth.php will help to tweet with media. Also, in your code, it's not

`$tweet->post('statuses/update', $params);`

Instead, it should be,

`$tweet->post('statuses/update_with_media', $params);`